# Multiple nullable composite foreign keys

Tags: c#, data-annotations, code-first

I'm a using Entity framework 6.1 & code first approach for my MVC project.

```
   public class PackageDaySchedule
{
public int Id {get;set;}
public DateTime Time {get;set;} 
Public int PackageId {get;set;}
Public int? PackageCity{get;set;}
public int? PackageHotelId {get;set;}
Public int? PackagePlaceToVisitId {get;set;} 
//navigation property 
public virtual Package {get;set;}
 public virtual PackageCity Package City {get;st;}
public virtual PackageHotel PackageHotel {get;st;}
public virtual PackagePlaceToVisit PackagePlaceToVisit{get;set;}
}

Public class Package {
Public int PackageId {get;set;}
Public List<PackageCity> PackageCities {get;set;}
}
Public class PackageCity{
[Key, Column(Order = 0)]
Public int PackageId {get;set;}
[Key, Column(Order = 1)]
public int CityId {get;set;}
public List<PackageHotel> PackageHotels {get;set;}
//virtual properties - Package and City
}
Public class PackageHotel{
[Key, Column(Order = 0)]
Public int PackageId {get;set;}
[Key, Column(Order = 1)]
public int CityId {get;set;}
[Key, Column(Order = 2)]
Public int HotelId {get;set;}

//virtual properties - Package,City, Hotel
}
```

For one PackageDaySchedule there should be a packageCity or packagehotel or PackagePlaceToVist. My question is how to specify foreign keys for the PackageDayShedule table using Data Annotations.
PackageId is common for PackageCity,PackageHotel & PackagePlaceToVist navigational properties.

Comment: First, using composite keys is almost always a bad idea. Second, using composite keys composed of foreign keys is *always* a bad idea. Third, using composite keys composed of *nullable* foreign keys is a simply catastrophic idea. Just use a regular `identity` or `uniqueidentifier` column as your primary key, and call it day.

Comment: Why you put this in MVC?

Comment: @ChrisPratt
thank u very much for the tip.  I will change the design according to your advice.

Comment: @ChrisPratt If you don't mind, could you explain me why I shouldn't use composite key for PackageCIty table. PackageCity is the many to many association (middle) table between Package and City entities.
(PackageHotel is many to many middle table of City & Hotel entities)

Comment: A composite key on a join table is usually okay. Hence why I said "almost always a bad idea" for that. However, having composite keys on tables you plan to query directly, especially if you're going to create further relationships to those tables begins to spiral out of control quickly.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification.

Answer (score 1):

A summary on how database tables is represented in asp mvc models

How Models represent database tables

In the following section I will be explaining how the data model is created for a database from the code first application, and cover how relation is represented in ASP MVC.

In this example we have three tables with the following schemas:

**Student table**

StudentID, LastName, FirstName, EnrollmentDate

**Course table**

CourseID, Title, Credits

**Enrolment table**

EnrollmentID, CourseID, StudentID, Grade

Each one of those table must be represented in a separate model.

1. **The Student Table**

   ```
   public partial class Student
   {

       public int StudentID { get; set; }
       public string LastName { get; set; }
       public string FirstName { get; set; }
       public Nullable<System.DateTime> EnrollmentDate { get; set; }

       public virtual ICollection<Enrollment> Enrollments { get; set; }
   ```

   }

The public virtual Enrollments is a navigation property which holds other entities that are related to this entity, e.g. the student entity in our case will hold data of all the enrolment entities that are related to him.

Tip: A table that has 1:M relation & it is on the 1 side, the model representation for it should include a navigation property of the M table and it should be a collection

2. **The Course table**
   Same as the student

   **3. The Enrolments table**

   ```
   public partial class Enrollment
   {
       public int EnrollmentID { get; set; }
       public Nullable<decimal> Grade { get; set; }
       public int CourseID { get; set; }
       public int StudentID { get; set; }

       public virtual Course Course { get; set; }
       public virtual Student Student { get; set; }
   ```

   }

The SudentID property is a foreign key and the corresponding navigation property is the Student. An enrolment entity is associated with one student entity, so the property can only hold a single student entity, that’s why we didn’t use IEnumerable.
Same for the courseID property.

Tip: The table on the M side should include the foreign key & the corresponding Navigation property but not a collection.

Comment: Thank  you very much!